# cmis addtofolder method do not create new cmisobjectid for target document for Alfresco repository

Tags: arrays, alfresco, cmis

When using method document.addToFolder(targetFolder, true); this is ok

when I delete the source document, target document is also deleted

does it's right behaviour ???

Comment: Add more clarity to your question

Comment: You mean document or folder ? Could you please be clearer on your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes...because the method addToFolder is used in multi filing scenario.

and multi filing keeps references not copy of the objects.

check here http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/os/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-os-complete.html#x1-3050005

Comment: Please how to copy all versions of a document because  iterate versions for copy one by one throws duplicate document exception.

Comment: As answered in your other question regarding versioning, if you really want to maintain those versions in your copy you are going to have to iterate over the versions and check them in, one-by-one, yourself.